# What's a "Xerox word"?

Tags: meaning

While reading [this (interesting) article about how to improve english and reduce accent](https://service.goodcharacters.com/blog/blog.php?id=175), I met a concept I've never heard about before: Xerox words.

> So I visited toastmasters.org and found a club close to me.
>   [...]
>   The club I go to uses a dog training clicker to call people’s
>   attention to their use of filler words like “mm,” “ah,” or **“Xerox”
>   words** like “I, I ...”, “We, we ...”

But I couldn't find any example online: what is it exactly ?

Comment: PS: not really familiar with english.se tagging: sorry if I did it wrong.

Comment: Xerox is a brand of photocopier and gets used instead of the word copy. So the stammering of I, I.. is a form of copying.

Comment: Oh ok; didn't know that this brand could be used this way.  Thanks, should be an answer imo ;)

Comment: Without the contextual _like "I,I...", "We, we ..."_ I wouldn't have understood the term either. As far as I know, the phrase "Xerox word" is not in normal use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where a brand name becomes known so well, it becomes used in place of the product. *Kleenex* is often used instead of *tissue*. In this case, Xerox is a brand of photocopier but *Xerox* gets used instead of the word *copy*. So the stammering of I, I.. is a form of 'speech' copying. The author was coining the stammering as making Xerox copies.

Comment: Then I don't understand the part of the sentence that follows and seems to provide examples: “Xerox” words **like “I, I ...”, “We, we ...”**

Comment: It just means "words that people repeat, like 'I, I ...', 'We, we ...'.

Comment: P.S. To the best of my knowledge, although *Kleenex* & *Xerox* may be misused as generic terms in this way in AmE, they are not (now)commonly used in this way in BrE (although *Xerox* was used generically in BrE some 30 years ago).

Comment: *Kleenex* is more predominantly used in place of *tissues* more so in the US. In the UK, it is very common to use *Hoover* in lieu of *vacuum cleaner* i.e. "I'll give the rug a quick Hoover."

Answer (score -2):

A “Xerox” word is a A **genericised trademark**.

> [**Generic trademark**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark) A generic trademark, also known as a **genericised trademark** 
>   or **proprietary eponym**, is a trademark or brand name that has become the
>   generic name for, or synonymous with, a general class of product or
>   service, against the usual intentions of the trademark's holder. Using
>   a genericised trademark to refer to the general form of what that
>   trademark represents is a form of metonymy.

It is based on an **[antonomasia](http://etymology.enacademic.com/5360/antonomasia)**:

> (n.) use of an epithet for a proper name (or vice versa; e.g. His
>   Holiness for the name of a pope), 1580s, from Latin, from Gk.
>   antonomasia, from antonomazein "to name instead, call by a new name,"
>   from anti "instead"

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, which is Why are I,I... and We, we... called *Xerox* words. Did you simply see **Xerox** and launch off onto a tangent?